# Move questions between Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, migration

I remember Jeff saying, when they announced Server Fault, that it was going to be possible to move questions between sites. I'd find that feature very nice as since then I've found at least 10 questions on either site that belonged to the other one.

Comment: @random It only took two years, *but it was worth it.*

Answer (score 65):

It might be useful to have a way to immediately move your own question before there are upvoted answers - similar conditions as for deleting your own question.

It happens too often that a question is voted on to belong to another site, but at the same time downvoted too. This could be prevented by immediately moving the question. Especially newbies not aware of the other sites will profit by this.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation on meta to upvote this. so i just add a comment: please add this feature. by all those sites now (stackoverflow, serverfault, superuser, etc.) it even happens that you post to the wrong site by accident.

Answer (score 62):

If you have 3k rep, you can nominate this by voting close: "belongs on serverfault.com" etc; at 5 votes it is moved by the system.

If needed, a ♦ moderator can do this immediately; so if it is obviously on the wrong site, but in a low traffic tag, consider flagging it for moderator attention.

Comment: I see 5 sites in list, but site to what question belongs on, is not in the list.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to have a way to alert the moderators that you'd like a question moved. This might be a big help to newbies.

Comment: You can always flag the question to require moderator attention and are then asked for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me to post a question on the wrong website and I'm just waiting to cast enough votes in order to have it moved (not to ask it twice).
Maybe a "self-voting" or "self-moving" could be quicker?

Comment: Well, just flag it for migration.

Comment: You are right, but this requires the intervention of a third person while I know it was my mistake... Anyway thanks, I've flagged it :)

Comment: “The fast option is to just delete and then re-post it on the new site” fit. – Catija♦ Jun 3 '19 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site/329029#comment1073824_329029

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be sone wholesale based on a tag?

If we can vote a tag as belonging to another site like "Server2008" then if someone uses it on Stack Overflow they are prompted to move the question at the point of entry?

It can say "Is this a programming question? if not it may belong one one of the sister sites...bla bla".

Comment: This doesn't really work if the author doesn't know how to properly tag their question, or if there is no defining tag that can be used for a particular scenario/question that isn't otherwise valid on the current site.

Comment: Correct, but it my kelp reduce the number of questions posted to the "wrong" place.

Comment: I think it's not correct all the time - to move a TAG. Assuming someone wants to connect an Android to an Active Directory 2K8, why should he be denied to use that tag?  I think it's a per question feature only.

Comment: @Saariko, Not denied use, but like MrHinsh said "prompted to move"--you could still have the choice but a helpful description would be brought to the user's attention highlighting the difference between a contextual tag and posting elsewhere entirely.

Answer (score -1):

It would be interesting, in the **remote future**, for the StackOverflow app to **expose *question moving* to its API**. That way a question could be moved from one SO website to another even if they have different owners.

Comment: With the platform not being an app and the network having one owner cc this is not even a relevant consideration any more.

Answer (score -5):

Click on 'flag' under the question, than go to:

'should be closed' >> 'off-topic because' >> 'Super User' or 'Server Fault'

Comment: Simply stating the name of a site where it would be on topic is not a close reason. Close reasons should explain **why** the question is closed... some questions can be on topic on more than one site. It is much better to comment on the question and say "This question is off topic here but would be within the scope of _____. You can flag your own question and request a moderator to move it for you."

Comment: The question is an old feature request. I don't think we need the usage guidance there as well. There are plenty of other places where that might fit or is already explained. The FAQ-posts comes to mind