# Creating a navigable tag tree based on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, search

Just for fun, how could I go about creating a navigable tag tree based on Stack Overflow?

It would be interesting to see the following somehow:

- Which technologies generate the most problems?
- Which technologies' questions are the most answered?
- Which technologies have the most helpful users (highest rep), and get answered most quickly?
- When is the best time of the week to ask questions for a given technology?

Comment: Belongs on meta...

Comment: I was thinking it would also be fun to know some statistics based on the ip addresses e.g. which country/region posts most about C++, C# etc. :-)

Comment: Yup, put that on meta, please.

Comment: <dunce hat>Is this something I need to do? i.e. raise it as a question on meta-stackoverflow? or is there a way of moving it over?

Comment: based on this, am flagging http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-overflow-sites

Answer (score 2):

You could first try creating a query at [StatOverflow](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) which uses a data dump of the whole site. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678) is a link to the schema for that site.

If you want to roll your own.. I would start your work by getting your own copy of the Stackoverflow Data Dump:

- [CC Stackoverflow Data Dump Nov
  09](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-09/)

This is a dump of all of the useful information about the site up to Nov09.