# Moving questions between SE sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0, math-se, mathoverflow

Specifically, between MathOverflow and math.stackexchange.com. Similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/move-questions-between-se-sites, which asks about moving between MathOverflow and StackOverflow.

Today, the private beta for math.stackexchange.com began, which differs from MathOverflow in that it covers more basic topics. In the past, questions have been deleted from MathOverflow for being too elementary. Soon, there will be someplace else for these questions to go.

Research-level questions that get asked on math.stackexchange (less likely) could potentially also be moved to MathOverflow. Has any progress been made since the last question on this topic as far as allowing the importing/exporting of questions on stackexchange sites?

Comment: There's a discussion on this over at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-overflow-sites.

Answer (score 1):

MathOverflow was an SE 1.0 site and therefore had no connection to math.stackexchange which is  an SE 2.0 site.

Other sites (UX, Electronics, Money, OnStartup) were migrated as the original sites were being shut down. MathOverflow is still going strong so there is no data to preserve.