# How do I move my own question to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I've posted a question to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/263460/how-to-get-data-between-tabs-in-google-spreadsheet) on Google Spreadsheets that I would like to move to [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/how-to-get-data-between-tabs-in-google-spreadsheet).

I think adding a function for moving the question to another Stack Exchange site (for the user who wrote the question) could be useful.

As [@Michael said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site#85041), a user with ***250 reputation***  could ask other users to vote to move his own question to another Stack Exchange site, so why not just let the user move his own question?

Since users with ***3000 reputation*** can move any question to any Stack Exchange site, experienced users can fix any inappropriate moves by inexperienced users, avoiding the delay of a vote.

Comment: Just flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Or wait until 5 people have voted for the migration.

Comment: I second this feature requst

Comment: I support this question and second this request.

Let's say I posted a question in a site. After sometimes, I gain a shining tumbleweed badge, or a couple of comments suggesting me to submit the question on another site.

Here, the answers so far suggest to flag the question. So to get the moderator to be involved in a trivial move.

Another possibility is to cut and paste the question's content. This sucks.

I say, keep it simple. With one click ('move to another site'), a destination site selection and a confirmation click, and the question is moved.

Really. Think about it.

Comment: @vitto Michael didn't say a user with at least 250 reputations can ask other users to vote to move their question(s). He said the so called user can do it themselves.

Comment: @Snack the exact phrase is "vote to close", which for ordinary users won't close/migrate it right away. They still need others to vote as well, hence it's kind of asking others to do that.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack It still doesn't make sense to wait until you reach 250 reputation to be able to ask others to vote to move your question to another website. You simply can ask a question regarding your demand on the per-site meta page even before reaching that threshold.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Users with [250 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/view-close-votes) can already [vote to close and move their own questions to other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-exchange-sites/2684#2684).

[image]

Users with [3000 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/close-questions) can do this for all questions.

The sites available as migration targets are limited though; this is what the dialog looks like on SO:  Flagging -> Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration

[image: Screenshot of the migration dialog]

If you want to migrate to sites not on that list, you need to have a moderator do it; flag the post for moderator attention and tell them which site you'd like it moved to

Comment: Thanks for this infos, I still would ask for this, why I should ask for this or need 3000pts of reputation to do something like this in my own question? I think it's more immediate if an user can move his own question by himself if he retain is useful to move it to another StackExchange site.

Comment: @Vittorio You don't, you only need 250 (see the first sentence of the answer). There's a small requirement because migrating to another site is non-trivial -- you need to understand the concept as well as understanding the target site and its policies. Even 5 3k users sometimes mess up and migrate a question to a site that doesn't want it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, This feature (moving to another site) doesn't seem to be working anymore right?

Comment: @Pacerier It should work fine; it still exists at any rate

Comment: @MichaelMrozek So I should push the "close" button, choose "off-topic" (with a dash) and see that? Well, I don't and I have 500 reputation on that particular site ...

Comment: @Liviu If it's your question, yes. What do you see?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek
`-> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.
   
->  Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.`

Do you say that the first two options (that I copied above) will just move my question if I push "Vote to close"?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek (continued) Well, they don't say that ... should I just trust you and vote it?

Comment: @Liviu No, the option to migrate says "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". If you don't see that then possibly it's not available to people under 3k, even on their own  questions; I'm not sure. You can flag for mod attention instead; I think if you choose "close for another reason -> off-topic" you should have the complete list of options. If not just choose "needs mod attention" and leave a comment saying it should be migrated

Comment: "Flagging->Closing->Off-topic" shows the same thing as "Closing->Off-topic". Maybe I'm restricted for constantly criticizing these sites (by example, this comments systime is plain idiotic: I'm forced to use a message box with the size less than 5% of my browser page)

Comment: I don't want to move anything now and, instead of asking one of the "helpful" policemen around here, I find much, much easier to copy-paste

Comment: @Liviu ...ok. Glad I took the time to help

Comment: Is this still the same? I would also like to see that a user can move their own question anywhere. The most likely scenario anyway is: you post - mod says, off-topic, better fit for xy. Then you either move to xy or it's copy-paste, or maybe beg for someones time - if you think in process instead of systems, you'll see that these are all the same, and artificial to require rep on one route (rep on which site anyway? I have different rep per site). Let tech enable processes.

Comment: Only a handful of sites are shown. How do I move it to AskDifferent for instance?

Comment: @shallowThought See the last sentence, under the image

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Ah. Thanks.  Does not make sense to me, especially for own questions.

Comment: This works except when it is "to old to move" like this on that should be in tex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633016/glossaries-package-and-footnote-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

I posted a question [Azure: How to move databases from different Azure SQL servers into Elastic Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351700/azure-how-to-move-databases-from-different-azure-sql-servers-into-elastic-pool) on stackoverflow and after a few days noticed that it doesn’t have enough attention. Now I think that a post on https://dba.stackexchange.com would give me more/better answers.

The recommended process to vote to close/migrate and wait for other 4 users to agree with the migration is too **slow**. It should be automated process to move my own questions with a few clicks. Otherwise users will just copy-paste, hopefully with cross-reference between questions on both sites.

Comment: The fast option is to just delete and then re-post it on the new site. As long as you don't have any upvoted or accepted answers, you should be able to delete the post without help.  Your only answer scores -1 so... just go for it.