# What's the best way to ask that my question be moved to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration

I asked [a question on Wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83301/how-to-allow-wordpress-and-laravel-to-share-top-level-urls-with-htaccess) which received the feedback:

> You can integrate Laravel functionality into WordPress, it's just PHP, but this question is way to open ended, voting to close unless you have a specific example your trying to get to work.

I took this on board, read a couple of entries on meta about improving questions, and reworked my question.

The rewrite was major: I have aimed for simpler goals to achieve my problem, but now the question is less relevant to the WordPress community, and the question is mothballing - not too many views, no answers, and a total of 2 comments.

I think the question is a better fit in its current form for Stack Overflow, but I don't have the 250 required to vote for a move...

What are my options?

- Ask here?
- Ask in the comments of the question?

Any recommendations?

PS. the only [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site) I saw like this one regards: "why can I not do this for myself", and does not answer my question

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a dupe.. the spirit of body of this question (5 years ago) was more "how can I appeal a close decision"... ChrisF's answer sorted me out...

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of [tag:faq] questions if the question is already answered in one of them. This is to keep all information in a standardized place. Also note that the proposed target offers the same advice as the answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog! At the time I didn't realise that there was a meta for each SE site! Close away :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag the question for moderator attention using the "other" option and explain why you want it migrated. If they agree and the question is less than 60 days old, they'll be able to migrate it.

There's no need to post here.

Comment: @memeLab - also if you have a question about a specific SE site then ask on that's site's meta. There's a link in the header of each page.