# Does a question about side effects of IE11 belong in Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration

So I just asked [this question about IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312250/how-to-fix-ie11-caused-hover-menu-items-becoming-watermarks-on-the-screen) in StackOverflow and realized it would probably be better of in Super User. Though not even sure about that? Does something like this belong in super user or stackoverflow.

I am asking because when I looked for a way to migrate myself and came across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site) were it was stated that migrating questions is non-trivial and wanted to make sure before flagging it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you are not programming IE (you would have to work at Microsoft to be doing that) so it does not belong at SO.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. It was not really programming related, but do you think Power User is the right place for it?

Comment: Yes, I do not know of any better place.

Comment: Mind doing it for me? On a another question (that I can't find) I read that users over 3k rep can some how do it? I know I can flag it but not actually do it.

Comment: At this moment the question has 3 votes against it, so it needs 2 more.

Comment: right, so even 3k can't actually move it, Thanks I'll flag it myself as well.

Comment: It just migrated now!